# Synchronization error in Kentico 8.0.21

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, kentico

While trying to synchronize in Kentico, a user go this error:

Synchronization server error: Exception occurred: Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\92YOrg\CMSFiles\f3\f3ef02ff-84bf-4ccb-b815-b807d8fd35f6.jpg' is denied.

The thing is that the file in question is actually on the E drive instead of the C drive, as it says in the error.  So why would Kentico think to look in the C drive?  I'm guessing that there is a setting somewhere that needs to be changed, but I've had no luck finding it.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd go back to your website in IIS and actually determine where in the file system your website is mapped to.

Second, ensure you have proper permissions set on the directories in the file system.

Comment: It was the permissions that were the issue.  Thanks to Juraj Ondrus from Kentico for pointing me in the right direction (but since Brenden answered correctly here, he gets the points ;) ) .   To give a more complete answer, the source website was in the E drive and the target was on the C drive.  The permission that had to be added was "modify" for the Network Service user.  One odd thing I feel I should note is that when I tried to sync again the process took a while and then failed.  Out of frustration I tried again and it worked fine, and other syncs are working as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to check **System > File > Storage** in *Settings* application.
[image]